# First WPF Project, the designer does not work

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

First project in WPF getting this error

> The type 'Window' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

When I build it it works well, while I could not see the designer, and I have made reload the designer a lot it is still not working. I also checked the the reference libraries added on my computer with another one (the designer works on it) there is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have formatted my computer , and the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Check you xaml code for that window if there is any error then design will not be visible.

Comment: I have not add any code , the errors appears tells that there is no reference  for Grid and window types

Comment: One on Window and the other on Grid

Comment: So could you help Mr  Mohini Mhetre ,please?

Comment: first of all I am Ms.Mohini Mhetre not Mr

Comment: I'm  sorry Ms.Mohini Mhetre.

Comment: Do you have a solution for me , answering the order above , actually I just made a new WPF project , and I check the references, I have omit them all and adding them again ,then I have got the same error

Comment: It is  4.5.1 .NET Framework (with number in registry 378758 )

Comment: Actually, I have as I said 4.5.1 framework ,but in VS 2010 it does not appear only framework 4.0 and less appears.so I have tried to build projects with frameworks less than 4.0 framework and everytime  I do that the visual studio stops working and restarts.so what do you see Ms.Mohini Mhetre